# Как сделать другую анимацию на третий клик? и Как сделать так чтобы префабы "выпадали" из объекта при разрушении?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал 2 анимации TreeDance.anim и Fall.anim. По моей задумке при первых двух кликах на дерево(мой объект) должна воспроизводиться анимация TreeDance.anim, а на третий Fall.anim.

Так вот, TreeDance.anim воспроизводится, а Fall.anim нет.

Объясните пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы при уничтожении дерева появлялись брёвна (ещё мои объекты).

Моя версия скрипта:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TreeDestroy : MonoBehaviour {

private int td;
public GameObject Log;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {
    if (td == 3) {
        Destroy (gameObject);
        Instantiate (Log);
        Instantiate (Log);
        Instantiate (Log);
    }
}
void OnMouseDown () {
    td = td + 1;
    if (td <= 2) {
        GetComponent<Animator> ().SetTrigger ("Dance");
    }
    else
        GetComponent<Animator> ().SetTrigger ("Fall");
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Чо это за вопрос вообще?

Comment: Я откатил назад и сделал замечание.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуй это:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destroyable : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int _td;

    public GameObject[] ObjectsToDrop;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        _td += 1;
        if (_td <= 2)
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Dance");
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Fall");
            StartCoroutine(WaitForAnimationEndDropItemsAndDestroy());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForAnimationEndDropItemsAndDestroy()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);//указать длинну анимации в секундах

        DropItems();

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    private void DropItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in ObjectsToDrop)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                var tmp = Instantiate(item);
                var zdvig = Random.Range(1,3);
                tmp.transform.location = new Vector3(tmp.transform.location.x + zdvig, tmp.transform.location.y+zdvig, tmp.transform.location.z);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас проверю

Comment: Вообщем помучился, помучился, но всё равно не получилось, всё что идёт после IEnumerator не работает

Comment: конкретнее? Какие ошибки, или какое поведение? Дебажил? Какое поведение конкретно ты видишь? Я же не оракул что бы самому узнать что у тебя идет не так.

Comment: Прости...
При дебаге
1)Пространство имён не может напрямую включать в себя такие члены как поля или методы.
2)Ожидался класс, делегат, перечисление, интерфейс или структура.
3)Ожидалось определение типа или пространства имён, либо признак конца файла.

Comment: кинул поверхностно протестированный код. Все работает как ожидалось.

Comment: Так, проверил, вставил всё которое нужно, но я не понял как это сделать, если у меня их много "не забудь задать локейшн у созданного итема такой же как у родителя + разброс"

Comment: через Random -- для каждого обьекта делаешь свой сдвиг по x и y осям(если 3д) относительно обьекта который уничтожаешь.

Comment: Как это сделать (Я самоучка... и возможно глупый...)?

Comment: Добавил, но код не проверял, если не сработает -- разбирайся сам. :)

Comment: Спасибо, ок, проверю

Comment: Не удаляй задачу когда ее решили -- кто-то может столкнутся с подобной задачей до твоей и вопрос/ответ могут им помочь. И перечитай правила пользования SO на всякий случай.

Comment: Удаление не добавит баллов, а "потертый"/испорченый вопрос наберёт ещё больше минусов.

Answer (score 0):

По коду вроде все правильно, вероятно ошибка в настройке анимации. Я бы посоветовал разумнее настроить `AnimatorController`. На сколько я понимаю у вас два состояния в нем и переходите вы в них устанавливая соответствующие переменные аниматора. Скорей всего дело в переходах. Я бы сделал параметр `State`типа `int` и в него при клике передавал ваш `td`. А дальше настроил переходы в контроллере из `AnyState` в ваши анимации по требуемым условиям со `State`. Если ваша анимация не должна крутится без остановки, то не забудьте в настройках перехода отключить галочку с переходом если уже находитесь в этом состоянии `Can Transition To Self`.

Если вы потом надумаете что дерево должно падать на 4 раз, вам не придется в код лезть чтобы исправить это, просто подправите контроллер.